# Polynomial PowerMod

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Is there equivalent of `PowerMod` for polynomials in Mathematica?

We have `Mod[a^e,m]==PowerMod[a,e,m]`, $a$, $e$ and $m$ all integers.

`PowerMod` is much more efficient for large $e$.

We have also `PolynomialMod[p1^e,p2]`, $p1$ polynomial, $e$ integer, $p2$ integer or polynomial.

For large $e$ it is inefficient.

Something like `PolynomialPowerMod` would be useful. Is there something like it? Or I have to write my own procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an *undocumented* function for this purpose: `` Algebra`PolynomialPowerMod`PolynomialPowerMod[] ``. For example, one could do

```
Algebra`PolynomialPowerMod`PolynomialPowerMod[-1 + x + x^2 - x^4 + x^6, 5, x, x^3 + 1]
   70 + 79 x + 8 x^2
```

which gives the same result as

```
PolynomialMod[(-1 + x + x^2 - x^4 + x^6)^5, x^3 + 1]
   70 + 79 x + 8 x^2
```

(I previously used the function [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26498) for computing a modular inverse.)

Comment: (Could a kind soul please evaluate the code snippet I gave, so that other people can see the expected result?)

Comment: I wonder why it is undocumented? Such a useful function. I was trying to write my own but it was not much efficient.

Comment: I cannot open the package :-(. I got this error: `Get::noopen: Cannot open Algebra`PolynomialPowerMod`.`

Comment: It's not documented because it is used directly by `PolynomialMod`.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: No, it is not used by `PolynomialMod`. That is why I asked. `PolynomialMod` is very slow for big exponents. But I just found out that it is used by 'PolynomialRemainder'. Although it has no separate argument for exponent, it works if you use it inside first argument as `p^e`.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: And by the way there are more functions used by other functions and still documented. So I do not understand why this one is exception.

Comment: Per J.M.'s request to run the snippet:     Algebra`PolynomialPowerMod`PolynomialPowerMod[-1 + x + x^2 - x^4 + 
  x^6, 5, x, x^3 + 1]      gives    70 + 79 x + 8 x^2          as does    PolynomialMod[(-1 + x + x^2 - x^4 + x^6)^5, x^3 + 1]

Comment: I'll ask about why PolynomialMod is not going that route.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Algebra/PolynomialPowerMod.html) from Wolfram,

> `` Algebra`PolynomialPowerMod ``
>
> The functionality of PolynomialPowerMod is now available in the kernel
> function PolynomialRemainder. Modulus is now an option to the kernel
> functions PolynomialQuotient and PolynomialRemainder.

I believe it is now possible to avoid this *undocumented* function `` Algebra`PolynomialPowerMod`PolynomialPowerMod[] `` by doing

```
PolynomialRemainder[(-1 + x + x^2 - x^4 + x^6)^5, x^3 + 1, x]
70 + 79 x + 8 x^2
```